# OSMDroid, Android - evoke pinch zoom programmaticaly

Tags: android, osmdroid

is there any view how to evoke pinch-zoom response in zooming objects programmaticaly? I am zooming certain objects, but only possible way is to pinch-zoom them, but I want user to give opportunity to zoom via zooming images + and -. Is there any way, how can I evoke pinch-zoom from written code?

Edit: this is not only OSMDroid related. It is question about simulating pinch zoom.

Thanks

Comment: What are these "certain objects"? If it is your own pinch-to-zoom implementation, call your own code. If it is somebody else's pinch-to-zoom implementation, we have to know what it is so we can help guide you for how to zoom through your own code.

Comment: its Osmdroid map view, max zoom is 16, and with pinch zoom I can see objects closer. When I drop my fingers, I am back to zoom 16, but when pinch zooming, I can see more datils and read streets name. Thats why I am asking to evoke pinchzoom programatically